# Passing raw data in axios request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, postman

I have to following request that i do with axios on Postman that works just fine but whenever i try to use it with axios i get an 500 error message.

How do i pass this raw data into axios so i can be able to make this post request.

In postman:

```
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json

Body:
Raw: {"value1": "someValue1", "value2": "someValue2", "value3": "someValue3"}
```

My axios call:

```
someCall() {
  axios
    .post("/some/call", {
    headers: {
      'content-type': ' application/json'
    },
     data: {
      value1: 'someValue1',
      value2: 'someValue2',
      value3: 'someValue3'
     }}
       )
    .then(res => {
      console.log("my call", res)
    });
},
```

The url works just fine because i already do some othe GET requests just fine.

Comment: Remove the key (`data`) from the second argument to `.post()`. should be a plain object.

Comment: oh, it worked. thanks mate.

Comment: As a side note, the header is not necessary as JSON is the default for Axios. So you can safely remove that.

Comment: thanks for the heads up.